# jaxbmarshaller spring boot could not find bean?

Tags: spring

I am trying to autowire in a jaxbmarshaler to use in my spring boot app.  It doesn't seem to recongise the marshaller.  The below is what I currently have, any tipson what I am missing

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
</dependency>

--- code

@Component

    public class DoSomethingService {

        @Autowired
        private Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;
        marshaller.marshal(MyObject,Stringwriter)
```

The error i get is saying it could not find the bean for Jaxb2Marsaller, any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

You need to have one or more configuration classes where all beans that should be available for autowiring should be defined. Its similar to defining the bean in spring applicationcontext xml

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller"/>
```

In java config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;

@Configuration
public class SomeName{
@Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        //any setters
        return marshaller;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks adding this in and it is now working.  in addition i had to add the packages i wanted to scan, and it worked

marshaller.setPackagesToScan("package");

Comment: above solution will work if we setPackageToScan

Comment: Worked after setPackageToScan. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use auto wire, you first need to create a Marshaller bean, pointing the necessary class/package to marshall. Then you can inject it.